# Large Number Of Spring Data / getHibernateLazyInitializer() method invocations

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jprofiler

We have a war file with a large number of JPA Entities utilizing Spring Data JPA 2.1.9. It is deployed on Wildfly 18 with JDK 11. Overall the system seams to run more slowly that the previous architecture. So we started using JProfiler to look for performance hotspots. While we are addressing problems found, JProfiler shows some very strange method invocation counts.

For example we have a simple JPA bean with 5 attributes and no associations. We are calling the repository finder method and it is returning say 200 JPA beans. However JProfiler is showing method invocations with names like:
*Bean$HibernateProxy$****.getHibernateLazyInitializer()

for multiple beans with counts in the millions .....the processing times individually aren't high...but you add up the different bean invocations and multiple seconds are being added to the system response time.

any idea what is causing the extra system overhead?